# SSJS - Cannot get the result of post request

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, webservices, ssjs, httprequest

I'm trying to send a post request via SSJS

```
var url = 'https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals';
var payload = '{"name":"wesh moose"}';
var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
req.retries = 2;
req.continueOnError = true;
req.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.setHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip");
req.method = "POST";
req.postData = payload; 
var resp = req.send();
```

To get the result i used this code :

```
var resultStatusStr = String(resp.statusCode);
var resultContentStr = String(resp.content);
var resultStatusJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.statusCode));
var resultContentJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.Content));
```

I got 201 which means that the request has succeeded, but i'am unable to get **the result** of the request, it's always 'null' :(

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you see, when you send the request via postman?

Comment: @SwatiMishra via postman i got this : {
    "animals": [
        "majestic badger",
        "fluffy bunny",
        "scary bear",
        "chicken",
        "wesh moose"
    ]
}

Comment: When you Write `resultContentJSON` did you Stringify it? If you try to Write a JSON Array or Object it will not write a result out.

Comment: also I do not believe you need to turn the resp.statusCode into a string then parse it. that returns an integer data type I believe.

Comment: @Gortonington Yes i do Stringify before write it, and you are right about the status code :)

Comment: So, just found the issue. You are doing `resp.Content` for the JSON and not `resp.content`. As SSJS is case sensitive, `resp.Content` is null as it was never defined but `resp.content` will contain the results of your API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from Comment to answer for easier reference.

You are doing `resp.Content` for the JSON and not `resp.content`. As SSJS is case sensitive, `resp.Content` is null as it was never defined but `resp.content` will contain the results of your API call.

So you need to change:

```js
var resultContentJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.Content));
```

into:

```js
var resultContentJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));
```

and then it will return the JSON Object you were expecting.

As a note too, the HTTP.POST solution you mentioned is definitely a great solution and it tends to be a less complicated way of doing it, but I usually recommend Script.Util.HttpRequest because of the versatility and customization you can get from it. But to be fair, it can be a bit much at times.

Comment: And we have a winner! I do agree that HTTP.POST is much easier than Script.Util.HttpRequest x)

Answer (score 0):

After spending more than 5 hours trying to figure out a solution, I decided to abandon **Script.Util.HttpRequest**  function and use instead **HTTP.Post** , you know what, IT WORKED!!

Here's the code :

```
var url = 'https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals';
headerNames = ["accept-encoding"];
headerValues = ["gzip"];
var payload = '{"name":"wesh moose"}';
var result = HTTP.Post(url,"application/json",payload,headerNames,headerValues);
var json = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response[0]);
Write('<br>Result: '+Stringify(json));
```